# Selected Background of Grid View Item disappears after Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using a Grid View to show a images from the phone. I used setOnItemLongClickListener like this to show a green border around the image.

Now the problem is, when I scroll down and come back, Green Border disappears but still I can get the position of longclicked item.

I understood views are recycling. But how can i hold hold the position and show the green background when user scrolls back to the actual selected image.

**I wrote this in my Activity**

```
MainView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                    arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    arg1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

**Here is my Adapter**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> images;
    ImageView imageView;
    private Activity context;
    public int width;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity localContext) {
        context = localContext;
        images = getAllImages(context);
    }     

public int getCount() {
        return images.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;

    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                width = getScreenWidth() / 2 ;
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(width,width));
            }
            else
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(imageView);

            return imageView;
        }

public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }
}
```

I'm not using any model class. I'm storing all image paths in a Array list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to write the

```
arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    arg1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

in your adapter `getView()` method by checking which position is clicked

Comment: I'm using setOnItemLongClickListener in my activity. How can I write set background and padding in adapter ? I don't want to call notifydatasetchanged to call getView again.

Comment: you get the view in getview and also you make a array which tracks which position was clicked and notify it, and without notify there is no other way

Comment: It worked but is there any way to refresh only selected position in the grid instead of refreshing all positions of the grid?

Comment: for that you have to use recyclerview which has notifyItemChanged(position) or call getview manually for that position

Comment: np glad i could help